# Fail to detect SPS30 particle sensor with I2C on Pi 3B

Tags: pi-3, gpio, i2c

I have connected a number of I2C sensors (BME280 temperature, humidity pressure sensor, a TSL2561 light sensor and MLX90614 IR thermometer) to a Raspberry Pi 3 and they work fine. I am now trying to add a [SPS30](https://www.sensirion.com/fileadmin/user_upload/customers/sensirion/Dokumente/9.6_Particulate_Matter/Datasheets/Sensirion_PM_Sensors_Datasheet_SPS30.pdf) - but without much success.

After asking here, I realised that I need a bi-directional Logic Level Converter - but this did not solve the problem. Any more suggestions?

I've attached a drawing of the circuit - unfortunately, the software does not distinguish between crossings and connections.[image]

```
> i2cdetect -y 1
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
00:          -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
10: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
20: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
30: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 39 -- -- -- -- -- -- 
40: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
50: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 5a -- -- -- -- -- 
60: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
70: -- -- -- -- -- -- 76 --
```

```
> uname -a
Linux raspberrypi 5.10.17-v7+ #1403 SMP Mon Feb 22 11:29:51 GMT 2021 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

[image]

Comment: Photos please.  What else is on the bus?  Output of i2cdetect?

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two problems with the level converter.

1. It is not connected to the breadboard.  It appears to be a loose fit over some header pins.  It needs to be soldered to the header pins.
2. The high and low +ve and -ve do not appear to be connected (if they are then SDA/SCL aren't connected).

Comment: I've removed the power cables for the picture to declutter - sorry. I soldered it on as well - but without success.